# Ves algun error en este Diagrama ER ? Es entendible?

Tags: diagrama-er

Mas alla de definir entidades, atributos y relaciones en un diagrama Entidad Relacion. Quisiera reflejar tambien las  limitaciones en dichas relaciones.

Para ello siempre caigo en duda por saber si lo he implementado bien o de que otra manera se podria hacer. Que no rompa con las reglas de un correcto ER.

Ejemplo: no he visto que un ER relacione dos relaciones. Siempre veo que hay relaciones entre entidades y nunca entre relaciones perse. Es un error ?

Hay dos puntos especificos que quisiera evaluar si estan bien implementados en este diagrama ( aparte de cualquier otra observacion o correccion que puedas encontrar ):

1. La limitacion entre la sede de una empresa y las actividades de una empresa. **una empresa podra establecer su sede en un pais donde no tenga actividades**
2. La entidad de captados. **un vendedor puede captar otros vendedores, pero dichos vendedores solo trabajan en la empresa donde trabaja el vendedor que los capta**

[image: Diagrama ER]

Comment: Preguntar qué opinamos sobre cómo se construye un ER es el tipo de pregunta que se cierra aquí porque estaría basada en opiniones. Por demás, no se vinculan relaciones entre sí porque estás especifican `relaciones` entre entidades que has modelado a partir del sistema que quieres representar y que interactúan entre sí. Y pues, no conocemos el sistema que estás modelando, entonces sería inoficioso decir qué está bien o no. Sólo puede decirse que tu diagrama es... difícil de seguir y es poco probable que pueda extraerse información de él para especificar una solución

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Imagina que todo el sistema se basa unicamente en los dos enunciados que he compartido en la pregunta. Quite la parte de "que opinan ustedes" por "cual es el error?".

Comment: el tema es que encontrar posibles errores dependerá del grado de conocimiento de cada usuario, dado eso para mi sigue luciendo basada en opiniones

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que estás intentando modelar aquellas restricciones de negocio en el modelo ER.
Aunque sería muy útil ver estas reglas en un sólo diagrama, el modelo ER no tiene por objetivo explicar todas las peculiaridades de una relación entre entidades, sino servir como una referencia rápida y simple.

Te aconsejo que mantengas tu modelo breve y lo anexes a un documento de diseño que explique las restricciones y peculiaridades del negocio que le da contexto.

Esto también te será útil a futuro porque, en la medida que la operación evolucione, verás que las reglas de negocio sufrirán diversas modificaciones y te será cada vez más tedioso mantener un diagrama actualizado. Omitirlas en el diagrama y expresarlas en otro documento, más adecuado a ese fin, hará que el primero extienda su tiempo de utilidad, pese a los cambios que se desarrollen en los procesos de negocio.